# Graceful Tomcat shutdown when Windows clustered service?

Tags: windows, tomcat, windows-cluster

We're currently in a situation where a Tomcat service is being brought offline by a batch script each night (or at the presence of a war archive, at least) in a Windows clustered environment.

The problem is that when Windows shuts down the tomcat service, it does not do so gracefully. This could mean (and has multiple times) that a service is listening and being used during the shutdown, alas terminating abnormally - or as in our case, we want to deploy a new webapp with the same name, but a jar file is being locked due to being in use.

Does anyone know of a nice way to gracefully shutdown the Tomcat service in this kind of solution? We're running Tomcat 5.5.

Comment: I know what you mean. You have to issue the shutdown command on the JVM. I'm flagging the question for interest's sake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [Windows service HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/windows-service-howto.html)? From looking at that it seems possible to change what happens at service start and stop after it is installed.

Comment: If I understand the service how-to correctly, it would seem that we could call something like "Tomcat5 //SS//Tomcat5" from the batch script at shutdown, then "Tomcat5 //TS//Tomcat5" to start it up? It's worth a short at least. Thanks for the link, +1.

Comment: By the way, wouldn't this cause problems since cluster services will try to bring the service online again? In such case, would I have to both use tomcat5 and cluster resource /offline, or what?

Comment: MSCS isn't my strong point but I'd say yeah you would have to take the cluster resource offline as well. Have a look at how [cluster.exe][1] works.

 [1]: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc723245.aspx

Comment: It would seem that //SS// doesn't close Tomcat very well, this might however be due to our installation and not normal behavior.

It would seem that what I was looking for is possible with the above answer, so I'm putting a resolve on this.